# Http request issue

Tags: android, web-services, http

I am unable to get the response from server when I am making request with http in android. I am calling one url that is working on browser, but default http client request giving me  reponse code 500 and response is below. What is missing?

```
<body>
    <h1>Cannot read property &#x27;_id&#x27; of undefined </h1>
    <p>[object Object]</p>
    </body>
```

Here is code

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        Log.v("", "url is: "+url);

        HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("http://54.255.228.162:3000/item?action=redeem&event=55018105f0df610b1c3919a2");

        try {


            org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            int responsecode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
} catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: This request does give the same error message when called from within a webrowser. Test it in two different browsers and you will see. May be you have some cookies set from a logged in session?

Comment: Yes it has cookies set on logged in session_id. what you are getting on different browser. I set session_id on http header but still same 500 error

Comment: Then may be you have to copy all request header fields, not only the session cookie.